# asp.net mvc script bundle not rendering with https

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ssl, https

I am getting this error message for script bundles which should render as https yet its return http://domain:443/

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://domain/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://domain:443/Content/css/mycss.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: what's the question? have a look at how you put the requests to the bundles, make sure that is over HTTPS and not HTTP

Comment: Show the code which includes the bundle on the page, please.

Comment: public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Content/js/jquery-{version}.js"));
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include("~/Content/js/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include("~/Content/js/bootstrap*"));
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css/css").Include("~/Content/css/custome.css"));
           
        }

Comment: I have this bundle in asp.net mvc Bundleconfig.cs. Web application is okay with http. It gives me mixed content error message if i use https.